# Apache rewrite engine not working on subdomain

Tags: mod-rewrite, yii, apache2

I'm using Yii framework and have the following code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

And I use this code in URL Manager to make SEO-URL's:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
  'urlFormat'=>'path',
  'rules'=>array(
  ''=>'site/index',
  'admin'=>'admin/default/login',
  '<action:\w+>'=>'site/<action>',
  array('page/view', 'pattern'=>'/<url:(\w|-)+>.html', 'caseSensitive'=>false),
  array('category/view', 'pattern'=>'category/<url:(\w|-)+>', 'caseSensitive'=>false),
  array('product/view', 'pattern'=>'product/<url:(\w|-)+>', 'caseSensitive'=>false),
),
  'showScriptName'=>false,
),
```

And it works perfectly on my local computer. But when I'm trying to apply it on my VDS i get server, ONLY when this code works on subdomains, e.g.: i have blah-blah.com - this code works, but if I have new.blah-blah.com (this is supposed to be different website, which has nothing in common with blah-blah.com) I get the following error (Internal server error 500):
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, [my email] and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

In apache's logs I found nothing about it.

Answer (score 0):

you can log errors to file or send to mail.

in your config/main.php

```
 'log'=>array(
                    'class'=>'CLogRouter',
                    'routes'=>array(
                            array(
                                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                            ),
                            array(
                                    'class'=>'CEmailLogRoute',
                                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                                    'emails'=>'yourmail@yourdomain.com',
                            ),

                    ),
             ),
```

Comment: I already logging errors and warnings, but the thing is, that I'm getting exactly apache's 500 error page and not something generated by Yii.